# SPADE installation

Tags: mobile, agents

I have a problem with SPADE( Plateform for Mobile Agents) when i'm trying to install it using command prompt. I got this error :

```
> Searching for pywin32 Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywin32/
> No local packages or download links found for pywin32 error: Could not
> find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pywin32')
```

Comment: Have you tried visiting this website and downloading `pywin32`?

Comment: yes but i got an empty page :(

Comment: Maybe try with this one from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

Comment: its not working too... i've installed an other version but its not working too

Comment: Works for me. Did you opened this up using python command ? `python setup.py --help` should list all commands for setup script

Comment: Thanks it works now